# Is there an equivalent to Java's 'this' inside a static class initializer?

Tags: java

I have a situation where a subclass (let's call it `SubClass`), during class initialization, calls a static method of the base class (let's call it `BaseClass`) and passes `SubClass.class` as a parameter to identify the specific class being initialized, or in Java:

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    static { BaseClass.init(SubClass.class); }
    ...
}
```

Instead of `BaseClass` having the method:

```
protected static void init(Class<?> c) {
    ...
}
```

what I would like to do is have `BaseClass` call `init` automatically, such as:

```
public class BaseClass {
    static { init(thisclass); }
    ...
}
```

So, the question is, does Java have some keyword, represented by `thisclass` above, that returns the class being initialized in a class initializer?

Comment: If you had multiple subclasses, how would the one base class static initializer initialize multiple of them?

Comment: The class being initialized in `BaseClass`'s static initializer blocks is always `BaseClass`. If you're expecting that initializer to run for subclasses, you'll need to adjust your expectations.

Comment: Perhaps think of this as an abstract problem.  I have boiled down the problem from my implementation, which works just fine, but I want to avoid having to tell the base class explicitly which subclass is being initialized.  In practice, I am storing the value SubClass.class as a key to a Map; the value to the map is information that BaseClass is tracking for each subclass.

Comment: Various instance methods in BaseClass recall this information by accessing the Map using the key this.getClass().

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

Also, as user2357112 said in the comments, the static initializer for `BaseClass` is only going to run once, while initializing `BaseClass`. It isn't like an instance constructor, run every time an instance of a subclass is created. Basically you should stick to your existing scheme.

It's also worth noting that if you're expecting subclasses to sort of "register themselves" with something, you may be surprised at when subclass initialization *doesn't* occur.

For example, if you have a static method `foo` in the base class, then calling `Subclass.foo()` *won't* initialize `Subclass` - only the base class, because the subclass doesn't *need* to be initialized, as none of its code is executing.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I missed the part about the base-class initializer running only once; I should have known that already.  While the current implementation works, I'll have to rethink the problem I am trying to solve to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments!  I reworked the implementation so that the base class calls its `init` method itself on behalf of a subclass the first time an instance method of the base class notices that the subclass is not registered.  This, unfortunately, costs a run-time check in the base class's instance methods, but it makes the registration fully automatic.

Answer (score -2):

No there isn't, because there is no instance at this point. Just as in a static method.